# I have some amount of bitcoin, how can i convert them to cash?

Tags: wallet

I also want to know how one can know his bitcoin wallet, i only see the bitcoin slip

Answer (score 0):

You can sell them on [Localbitcoins](https://localbitcoins.com/sell_bitcoins) , the idea is to find a local buyer and meet him face-to-face.